# php find total datetime difference in seconds not getting as expected

Tags: php

I am trying to take the differences of datetimes in php as follows:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime();
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-09-23 08:09:50');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$elapsed = $interval->format('%S'); 
echo $elapsed;
```

Here I am getting the difference in seconds.

I need the total time difference in seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$difference = abs($datetime1->getTimestamp() - $datetime2->getTimestamp());
```